# Django Rest Framework - AssertionError in tests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I have a problem with Django Rest Framework's tests. I have a following view:

```
class AccountDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    model = Account
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Account.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

My urls include the following:

```
account_urls = patterns('',
    url(r'^/(?P<username>[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/$', AccountDetail.as_view(), name='account-detail'),
    url(r'^/$', AccountList.as_view(), name='account-list')
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/v1/users', include(account_urls)),
)
```

When I use the browsable API, everything works alright, but when I write the following test, I get an error:

```
class TestAccoundDetail(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        #set up normal user and token
        self.normal_user = Account.objects.create_user(email="user@example.com", username="useri", password="man")
        request = factory.post('/api/v1/auth/login/', {'email': 'user@example.com', 'password': 'man'})
        response = obtain_jwt_token(request)
        self.normal_token = response.data['token']

    def test_details(self):
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        view = AccountDetail.as_view()

        #unauthenticated
        url = reverse('account-detail', kwargs={'username': 'useri'})
        request = factory.get(url)
        response = view(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

AssertionError: Expected view AccountDetail to be called with a URL keyword argument named "username". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

URL seems fine, and the lookup_field is there. What am I missing?

### EDIT

I used APIClient instead and it works:

```
        client = APIClient()

        response = client.get('/api/v1/users/useri/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

However, I still don't understand why my original test did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on @linovias answer, the key is to pass the extra arguments to your view

```
response = (view, username='useri')
```

Full test

```
def test_details(self):
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    view = AccountDetail.as_view()

    #unauthenticated
    url = reverse('account-detail', kwargs={'username': 'useri'})
    request = factory.get(url)

    response = view(request, username='useri')

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 5):

RequestFactory is to unittest views. It does bypass the middleware and the url layer. Therefore you need to provide the additional arguments by yourself while with the ClientFactory urls.py do it for you.

Edit:
In other words,

```
response = view(request)
```

should be

```
response = view(request, "useri")
```